# Spinnaker configuration loaded as code from gitlab

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

It is really good that we have spinnaker pipeline as a code from roer and other tools. But is there a way that we will store these pipelines and as well as configurations on gitlab and restore by just fetching the files from gitlab? without really manually inserting the configurations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Save Pipelines" stage.

See related commit for [details](https://github.com/spinnaker/orca/commit/9ae64a9040986ec2685c61cede090807f8706f11#diff-7fa8b7a152554a177280d92fd6a2f1b9).